# What have to be done in order to enable Cloud Pub/Sub as a Notification Channel n Google Cloud

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-pubsub

Steps to reproduce:

Step 1: I have created only two itens in Google Cloud: (1) Firestore Database under Firebase umbrella and Google Cloud Pub/Sub

Step 2: I created a Policy alert in Firestore which will be triggered if there is one write in one minute. Obviously this metric is aimed for learning purpose.

Step 3 - I added in this Policy email channel and it works as expected. I mean, soon I write any document in Firestore collection I get an email. So far so good.

Step 4 - Now I want to create a second Policy with Pub/Sub channel pointing to the Google Cloud Pub/Sub and no matter what I try this option is frozzen/unable as you can see in this picture

[image: Pub/Sub unable]

So my straigh question is: how enable such Pub/Sub Channel Option for my Policy? Surronding questions are: isn't possible to use Pub/Sub Channel option in free account? I guess I can use since I didn't read any instruction about this. Certainly must exist some limitation but I will be glad to use the minimal for now.

In case it adds some important info, here is my Pub/Sub:

[image: Pub/Sub]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a little bit of notifications before, so I dig a little bit in the GCP documentation and I have found a step-by-step on what to do in order to set the PubSub notification.

The link is the following [1] and you have the steps to configured your PubSub.
Basically, you after creating your PubSub topic, you have to create the notification channel.

Go to Monitoring > Setting (in the right corner there's a blue button "Notification Channels" and in there you will find the section for the PubSub, the link I sent you has more detailed info, but roughly this is what you were missing.

I hope it helps you out.
Cheers!

[1] - https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#pubsub

Comment: Hey,
I've only realise this now, you might want to check you screenshot again as you may not have seen that you have published your project-id on it and you may want to remove them to avoid security issues.
=)